# See user's reputation on website on specific date in "Reputation" tab

Tags: feature-request, reputation, profile-page

Currently, when I go to my or someone's other "Reputation" tab in profile, I see something like that:

[image]

It would be really nice, if I will be able to see my/somebody's other reputation score specific day (not only reputation change), like:

[image]

I think that is really useful in some cases, is comfortable, looks nice and gives a chance to fill somebody in. What do you think?